# Networking with Jobscheduler

Tags: android, android-networking, android-jobscheduler

Is networking using HttpUrlConnection etc (for uploading data to server) possible with JobScheduler? Or I've to go with GCMNetworkManager? How can I perform network operation scheduling?

MainActivity.class

```
jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
btnStartJob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ComponentName jobService =
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyJobService.class.getName());
        JobInfo jobInfo =
                new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(10000).build();

        int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
        if(jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)>0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Successfully scheduled job: " + jobId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "RESULT_FAILURE: " + jobId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}});
```

MyJobService.class

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    public MyJobService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"MyJobService.onStartJob()",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //networking is not working here
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "MyJobService.onStopJob()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is networking using HttpUrlConnection etc (for uploading data to server) possible with JobScheduler?

Of course. You should use the `.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)` on the JobInfo builder though, to ensure your job does not run if there is no network available.

You have to do your network operation in JobService on a separate thread though, because the onStartJob is executed on the main thread.